# How to default Remote Desktop to use my 2nd monitor?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I use Remote Desktop on Windows 7 pretty often, but I find it frustrating that RD defaults to show new RD windows on my default monitor (which is a laptop).  I'd prefer to have RD show new windows on my 2nd monitor.  I can't find a setting that allows me to do set this default behavior.  The steps that I usually end up doing is:

1. Start up Remote Desktop
2. Connect to a machine
3. Un-Maximize the window size so I can drag it to my 2nd monitor
4. Cancel out of logging in to the remote machine
5. On the Remote Desktop connect window, set my window display size to Full Size
6. Connect to the remote machine (which now displays on my 2nd monitor)

A lot of steps that I find annoying to do, especially when I'm connecting to different machines and really don't want to run through all these steps over and over.

I'm assuming there has to be a default setting that I'm missing.  I'd appreciate any help with this (hopefully) obvious question.

Answer (score 2):

@Ivan's answer over here is terse but correct, at least for my use in Windows 8.  If you look at my comment under his post you'll see the explanation.

https://superuser.com/a/504425/1943

Further, if you want it automatically fullscreen set the winposstr like in his answer, but also set `screen mode id:i:2` where 2 means fullscreen (1 means windowed).