# Make RDP full screen on secondary or multiple monitors?

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, windows-server-2003

I want my RDP or remote desktop window to occupy the whole area of my secondary screen (which is bigger than primary). I tried everything in this microsoft doc and it does not work - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/665.how-to-set-the-monitor-for-a-remote-desktop-session-in-a-multi-monitor-setup.aspx

I am trying to connect a windows 7 64 bit system to a Windows server 2003 64 bit. How do I do this ?

Comment: okay, this is a complete fluke. I just copy pasted this line from the link above - 

    winposstr:s:0,1,1200,0,2880,1050

and it worked. I did not think this through or find the resolution of my screen or anything. It just worked. It may not work for you if your setup is different from mine.

Comment: I was going to suggest http://superuser.com/a/100672 as well

Comment: @RandolphWest - actually, I tried a couple of answers from there too and it did not work. Besides, there is no break key on my computer.

Comment: Wow ok. Well, if the winposstr worked, post it as an answer so that the question can be closed.

Comment: @RandolphWest - I need to wait for 7 hours to do that. :)

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, press `Win-P` until "Projector Only", this should make your secondary screen to  be only monitor.

[image: ProjectorOnly]

Then RDP in Full Screen. once connected, press `Win-P` until Extend, then drag the RDP window to secondary screen.