# windows 10: prevent remote desktop from "seeing" second monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

i use sonicwall remote access for my computer at work, but i have two monitors at home. when i connect, windows automatically assumes i want my remote desktop to occupy both monitors. since my remote desktop is a single screen, that means my second monitor at home is just black and empty.

if i resize the window, i lose access to my remote screen's taskbar. it also reduces my usuable remote screen size because of the scroll bar on the side of the window and the title bar at the top.

is there a way in windows 10 to limit remote desktop (or any program) to just one screen?

my current workaround is to unplug the 2d monitor, launch remote, and then plug it back in, but this is inelegant (and sometimes i accidentally unplug my adjacent ethernet cable).

EDIT: to clarify that i am using sonicwall, not windows native remote desktop.

Comment: Have you tried the maximization trick from [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/100668/how-do-i-open-a-remote-desktop-session-on-a-secondary-monitor)?  Maybe I'm not understanding correctly - when I use RDP to connect from a two-monitor computer to a remote one-monitor computer, it only ever uses a single screen.

Comment: You have tagged it "remote-desktop" but it doesn't sound like you are using Windows' inherent RDP; because when using RDP, the desktop shape and size of the server means nothing, as the RDP client gets it's own desktop created for it, which can/will resize automatically.  So which remote desktop solution are you using (make and version)?  You also mention Windows 10, but have not clarified if that's the OS on both the client and the server side...

Comment: Techie007, you're right!  i fixed the text and tags.